# Merged questions from Gadgets are causing tag anomalies

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags, stackexchange-2.0

With the closing of gadgets.se, numerous questions were auto-merged into apple.se. Unfortunately, we're now getting some weird tag side-effects.

1. Many tags now show as duplicated. No, they're not just ones that look similar, they're actually listed twice with the same number. For instance, see *accessories* or *address-book* on [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name).
2. Because of the duplicate weirdness, some questions have ended up with more than five tags. For instance, [iOS keyboard settings change on their own](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/ios-keyboard-settings-change-on-their-own) has seven (5 actual + 2 dupes).
3. When I try to clean up the tags, things get even hairier. For instance, when I tried to remove the *mobile-phone* tag on [Least expensive prepaid data roaming with an unlocked iPhone in the US](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/least-expensive-prepaid-data-roaming-with-an-unlocked-iphone-in-the-us), the question ended up with *prepaid* twice. Right now, it has four tags (3 actual + 1 dupe)—but when I try to add another, I get the message that the question already has five tags.

Comment: Wow, that's looking pretty rough.

Comment: We're working on a fix for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate tags have now been removed.